# If my templated type occurs firstly as a lambda argument, MSVC raises a strange error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Consider this code:

```
#define SOLUTION 0

template <class T>
constexpr int one = 1;

template <class T>
struct A {
    static constexpr int o = one<A<T>>;

    void call() {
        static_assert(one<A<T>> == 1, "Failure");
    }
};

int main() {
#if SOLUTION
    A<int> object;
#endif

    [](A<int> a) {
        a.call();
    };

    return 0;
}
```

It builds successfully [here on ideone](http://ideone.com/oOq3mJ), regardless of the value of `SOLUTION` define.

Now, I know that this code makes little practical sense, but that is because I was trying earnestly to find the minimal working example of this strange behaviour. If I build this with the latest Visual Studio 2017 (platform toolset v141, _MSC_VER = 1910), I get the following error:

```
1>source.cpp(11): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
1>source.cpp(11): note: failure was caused by a read of an uninitialized symbol
1>source.cpp(11): note: see usage of 'one<A<int>>'
1>source.cpp(10): note: while compiling class template member function 'void A<int>::call(void)'
1>source.cpp(21): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void A<int>::call(void)' being compiled
1>source.cpp(21): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'A<int>' being compiled
```

Funnily enough, when I put 1 for the `SOLUTION` macro, it builds successfully. The only difference is that an unused `A<int> object;` variable is defined in `main`'s scope before the compiler gets to the lambda definition.

It is also perfectly fine if, before main, I define a function like this:

```
void f(A<int>& a) {
    a.call();
}
```

In fact it solves the problem equally well as does the variable definition.

Is it a compiler bug or is the above chunk of code in violation of the standard?

Comment: Compiles on VS2017 update *3*, but not on (RTM) update 2.

Comment: @Ajay Strange, my VS2017 version appears to be the latest, updated as of May 30, so literally 3 days ago. Perhaps it's important whether it's the Community version or not (mine is Community)? I've also noticed the devs about the problem here:
 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/63753/unexplainable-compilation-error-due-to-a-lambda-de.html I've also confirmed it does not happen on just my own machine.

Comment: I have installed preview version of update 3, which has many C++17 features.

Comment: @Ajay Wow, didn't know about the preview! I'll try it out immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [Ajay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307588/if-my-templated-type-occurs-firstly-as-a-lambda-argument-msvc-raises-a-strange#comment75655297_44307588):

> Compiles on VS2017 update 3, but not on (RTM) update 2

I've confirmed this behaviour on my machine as well. This means that the relevant corrections exist and will be introduced soon enough to the production version itself, so I believe that this bug is unworthy of further notice.